# Android Automotive OS Video

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-video-player, android-automotive, automotive

I'm trying to implement simple automotive app where I can display hardcoded video. I checked documentation and there is the automotive app category for that case, but when I look for more code  snippets or documentation - there is nothing. I cannot find automotive template which can display a video and I'm not sure how can I tackle this.

[image]

https://developer.android.com/training/cars/parked/video

Thank you in advance for all of the information!

Comment: Video apps are not supported while the car is driving therefore there is no need to use templates. You can just create a regular app